# Проблема с установкой пакетов python

Tags: python, pip

Пробую установить пакет simple-crypt через cmd. Выдает ошибку, не могу разобраться в чем проблема.

```
C:\Users\AC>pip install simple-crypt
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting simple-crypt
  Using cached simple-crypt-4.1.7.tar.gz (10 kB)
Collecting pycrypto
  Using cached pycrypto-2.6.1.tar.gz (446 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for simple-crypt, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for pycrypto, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: pycrypto, simple-crypt
    Running setup.py install for pycrypto ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\program files\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\AC\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-97e1rubs\\pycrypto_9e3114af141e4a3a8323477d48c6d878\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\AC\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-97e1rubs\\pycrypto_9e3114af141e4a3a8323477d48c6d878\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\AC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-jgk3kz01\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\AC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Include\pycrypto'
         cwd: C:\Users\AC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-97e1rubs\pycrypto_9e3114af141e4a3a8323477d48c6d878\
```

Comment: Попробуйте установить пакет wheel, про который написано в ошибке, потом уже simple-crypt

Comment: @insolor, к сожалению не помогло.
Collecting simple-crypt
  Using cached simple_crypt-4.1.7-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pycrypto
  Using cached pycrypto-2.6.1.tar.gz (446 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: pycrypto
  Building wheel for pycrypto (setup.py) ... error
Далее та же ошибка, по кол-ву символов не проходит в комментарий.

Comment: Добавьте текст ошибки в сам вопрос.